# Excel IFS Formula multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Here is my original formula for cell T3:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(S3),S3="None"),DATE(YEAR(B3)+18,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)),"N/A")
```

I would like to add the following to the formula above...

- If the word Closed is in cell F3, I want it to put Closed in T3
- If the word Active in cell F3, I want it to do the formula above.

I just can't figure out had to add the additional criteria to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably almost have it. I can tell that you have a grasp of the basic concepts.

The structure of IFS is:

=IFS([Something is True1, Value if True1,Something is True2,Value if True2,Something is True3,Value if True3)

So, just substituting in your requirements, you'd need:

```
=IFS(F3="Active",IF(OR(ISBLANK(S3),S3="None"),DATE(YEAR(B3)+18,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)),"N/A"),F3="Closed","Closed")
```

The value of "Value if True1" is the embedded conditional that you already arrived at before asking the question.